# How to solve "Account using more than allotted RAM usage"?

Tags: ram, accounts, ram-allocation

I am trying to unstake my EOS tokens using `system undelegatebw`. I got the error `Error 3080001: Account using more than allotted RAM usage` and `account xxxxx has insufficient ram; needs 7973 bytes has 7797 bytes` when I tried to run the command. How to solve this issue? How can I buy more RAM to my account?

Answer (score 3):

You can buy more RAM for your account xxxxx:

```
cleos system buyram xxxxx xxxxx "10 EOS"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather not want to use the command line or a wallet, I built a tool that lets you buy more RAM using credit card or crypto (Bitcoin, Bitcoin Cash, Ethereum, Litecoin).

The tool is here: https://eos-account-creator.com/buyram/

I hope it's useful to some people.